# Session.run() /Tensor.eval() of Tensorflow run for a crazy long time

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn tenforflow by following the [Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html) tutorial, but when I was trying to figure out how `cifar10_input.py` loads data from `cifar-10-batches-bin`, I encountered a problem that `Tensor.eval()` executes for a very long time or runs forever without a result.
The code is like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 import cifar10_input

filenames = ['/Users/me/Downloads/cifar-10-batches-bin/data_batch_1.bin']
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
read_input = cifar10_input.read_cifar10(filename_queue)
reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print reshaped_image.eval()
```

The code is basically from `cifar10_input.py` and the file `data_batch_1.bin` is
extracted from `cifar-10-binary.tar.gz`。

Normally, I can observe a tensor using its `eval()` method. But in this case it runs continually for a longer time than ever（I waited for nearly an hour and it was still running). Is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1)  As a basic sanity check:  `ls -al /Users/me/Downloads/cifar-10-batches-bin/data_batch_1.bin`

2) Don't forget to:

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
```

3) `tf.train.start_queue_runners()`  (after creating your session)

It's probably #3.  The [`string_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer) adds a queue runner to the `QUEUE_RUNNERS` collection, which needs to be started.

Comment: Thanks very much, the #3 really solved my problem, but actually the method should be `tf.train.start_queue_all_variables()`.

Comment: Whoops, right - thanks, accepted your update to fix the typo.

Comment: Thank you so much!